# Exercise Equipment: Create Adjustable Rope Loop

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, strength, exercise-equipment

I am looking for a way to create an Adjustable Circle Loop with Rope.

I can do this with Gymnastics Ring Straps using a Buckle system (seen below).

Just curious if there is any equipment to  create an adjustable loop with Rope specifically (doesn't have to necessarily use buckle). Wanted to insert the rope between Weight Plates and Work on Rope Grip Strength.

[image]

Any method to prevent manually tying/knotting rope myself, and have it Easily adjustable is good. Will need rope length to be adjustable for many different exercises.

Comment: What about using a Duncan knot? https://www.takemefishing.org/how-to-fish/best-fishing-knots-for-lures/how-to-tie-duncan-knot/ 

This is a question about knots rather than fitness, isn't it?

Comment: hi @ParibusCeteris I am trying to prevent knotting/tying the rope myself, but have it Easily adjustable thanks

Comment: Can't you use rope wrapped chain instead? Just making dumb suggestions in hope one is useful

Comment: hi @ParibusCeteris what is that? can you send a picture in a link? thanks

Comment: Heh, sorry. I meant that you grab a chain and make yourself a handle with rope to hold the chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like a [loading pin](https://www.roguecanada.ca/rogue-loading-pin). This one is from Rogue but I know GripGenie makes a high quality one and Amazon would have some knockoffs for cheaper. You could put your rope on a carabiner and wouldn't need to worry about it being adjustable; just knot it tight, and clip it to the pin.

The second suggestion would be the same method but swap the pin for some chains. Knot your rope to the a carabiner, run the chains through the weights, and clip the chains in. A bit less elegant but still functional.

The third idea would be to just tie a fat permanent knot on one end of the rope, larger than 2", so that Olympic weights can fall through. Then just weave the rope through the weights. You could also just make a cow hitch through the weight plates and grab one end. That's easily adjustable but you'd have to tie/un-tie each time.

For clarity, I drew the ideas. I'm having a slow morning. Happy grip training!

[image: Scuffed MSPaint Drawing of Rope Implements]

---

For creating a loop in the rope to hold I would look toward the camping, climbing, outdoor hobby areas. Google something like an "adjustable rope clamp". A few I see that would work are something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pE_fY9ZC0mw), or [this](https://theropeclamp.com/2016/10/rope-fastener/), or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQOuikG02Q8).

I'm not sure what kind of grip exercise you're trying to do. The rope grip attachment I have access to is a rope connected with a [rope clamp](https://www.amazon.ca/Forellfit-Clamp%EF%BC%8CRope-Attachment-Equipment-Carabiner/dp/B08MVW7SJY/ref=asc_df_B08MVW7SJY/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=459263885007&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17237248728875184477&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001171&hvtargid=pla-1281541986192&psc=1) to the loading pin setup I drew. You then work the grip unilaterally.

Comment: thanks, but what I am really looking for is rope length to be easily adjustable for many different exercises just like the strap/buckle above, manually knotting will not work

Comment: @mattsmith5 -- added some loop ideas. Also, like paribus said, you could take a length of rope, add the rope clamp I linked to both ends, and complete the loop with chain.